# Run two processes at a time

Tags: python, process

I want to run two processes at a time. I am using os.system to run the processes. The first one runs perfect, but the second is not running. How to run the processes at same time.

Comment: So that we can check, can you post the code of what you were trying to do?

Comment: os.system("C:\\app1.exe -x C:\\file.txt  & \app2 -p 1,2,0,0") C:\\app1.exe -x C:\\file.txt --- is the first command to be executed and has to be running all the time. while the first command is running i have to run the second command. but i assume the second process will run only after first exits or returns. can u give me example of using multiprocess module for my situation. Thanks.

Comment: @pikapika Are both `app1` and `app2` both OS executable files?

Answer (score 1):

(Having not seen your code yet, based on what I understand from the question)
You have a python program running and want to spawn another python process from the first one.

If so,
Use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module from the standard library.
It is much better suited for running 2 (python) processes than `os.system`.
It is mainly used for concurrency and simultaneous execution of code.